How to handle "exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB" when migrating from Azure DevOps to GitHub using Git LFS?
I'm in the process of migrating a repository from Azure DevOps (ADO) to GitHub and encountering issues with large files during the push process. I'm following these steps:
git clone <github-repo-clone-url>
cd <github-repo>
git clone --mirror <ADO-Repo-clone-url>
cd <ADO-Repo>/
git push --mirror <github-repo-clone-url>

I have tried multiple things such as Partial Push, git lfs migrte, the git lfs migrate will rewrite the commit which I dont want and then I tried to push using

--mirror

However, while pushing the changes, I receive the following error message:

file is  162.64 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB

what other things I can I try?
Thanks alot for your help and appreciate for the answers in advance

If there are blobs that are more than 100 MBs in the history of the branch/branches that you are trying to push, github won't allow it... it's their restriction, no workarounds.

You could rewrite history to remove them if possible..... or you might use LFS...... but with the branches including those files, that's not going to fly.

Hello @eftshift0, so whats happening is the files which has LFS issue its present in the git  History, and not in the present state, so is it some how I can remove them and delete it?
becuase even That also I am not able to do it , and to keep the clean enviornment thats why I dont want to rewrite the commit history.

Changing the content of files in the history (which includes moving it to git lfs) is rewriting the history, so you can't get that without rewriting the history. In other words: if you can't rewrite the history, then you won't be able to mirror this repo to github, as you exceed their limits.
